Mocking a function which calls others functions
# Function to be tested
#### process.py
def process_data(ctx, dump, data):
    mode, id = get_event_values_from_context(ctx, MODE, ID)
    logger = get_app_value_from_context(ctx, LOGGER)
    dao: conn.DB = get_app_value_from_context(ctx, DB)
    returned_value = dao.fetch_one(get_app_value_from_context(ctx, DB_STR), MODE['name'], data._keys)


# Util Functions
#### util.py
def get_app_value_from_context(ctx, key):
    return getattr(ctx.user_data, key)

def get_event_values_from_context(ctx, *keys):
    return (ctx.user_data.event_data.get(key) for key in keys)

# Test module
####test.py
@pytest.fixture
def context(model):
    ctx = MagicMock(name='NuclioContext') # Nuclio Context object
    ctx.user_data = MagicMock(name='user_data')
    setattr(ctx.user_data, 'logger', MagicMock(name='logger'))
    setattr(ctx.user_data, DB, MagicMock(name='db'))
    setattr(ctx.user_data, DB_STR, model['name']) # it has user_data attributes
    setattr(ctx.user_data, 'event_data', { # it's a custom dictionary added to it
        'mode': mode,
        'row_key': "0906343754"
    })
    ctx.user_data.DB.return_value.fetch_one.return_value = None
    # ctx.user_data.DB.fetch_one.return_value = None ## this is also not helping 
    return ctx

@pytest.fixture(params=[data1Obj, data2Obj
])
def serialized_data(request):
    return request.param

@pytest.fixture(params=[serializedData1, serializedData2
])
def output_dump(request):
    return request.param

@pytest.fixture
def model():
    return {
        "key":"value" # pairs
    }


@patch('util.get_app_value_from_context')
@patch('dbs.conn.DB.fetch_one', return_value=None)
def test_process_data_empty_payload(mock_fetch_one, mock_get_app_value, context, serialized_data, output_dump):
    returned_payload, _ = process_data(context, output_dump, serialized_data)

    assert returned_payload is None

fetch_one is from another dependent module which name is dbs and it has a package called conn and a class called DB which has a function fetch_one. I am trying to mock this function to return None. But it returns Mock object.
Could someone help me with this?

EDIT
def test_process_data_empty_payload(mock_fetch_one, mock_get_app_value, context, serialized_data, output_dump):
    returned_payload, _ = process_data(context, output_dump, serialized_data)

    assert returned_payload is None

And
def process_data(ctx, dump, data):
    mode, id = get_event_values_from_context(ctx, MODE, ID)
    logger = get_app_value_from_context(ctx, LOGGER)
    
    returned_value = context.user_data.DB.fetch_one(get_app_value_from_context(ctx, DB_STR), MODE['name'], data._keys)

This piece of code works. I believe that getattr caused the earlier test to fail.
How could I overcome this?
